# Why booleans always update false?? (Moongose)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, helper

I would like to knwo why using the Query findOneAndUpdate, overwrite some data and don´t update booleans, always are false.

```js
exports.userUpdateInterest = (req, res) => {
  let keys = Object.keys(req.body);
  if (keys.indexOf('email') > -1) {
    User.findOne({ 
      email: req.body.email
    }).exec(async (err, user) => {
      console.log("execuser",user)
      const update = {
        onboarding: req.body.onboarding,
        oneToOne: req.body.oneToOne,
        nps: req.body.nps,
        questions: req.body.questions,
        comunication: req.body.comunication
      };
      try {
        let document = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
          { email: user.email },
          update,
          { returnOriginal: false }
        );
        console.log("res", document)
        res
          .status(200)
          .send({ message: 'User update success!', user: document });
          console.log("res", document)
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'User update fail!' });
      }
    });
  }else{
    res.status(400).send({ message: 'Missing email field!'})
  }
};
```

I have try to change de query and nothing is working, at least, on my unless knowment. Any help please?

Comment: That code snippet doesn't show any booleans at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.